# I'm having a issue getting a string

Tags: c#, string, multithreading

IN my program.cs I have this:

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        String user = null;
        using (var login = new loginForm())
        {
            user = login.returnUser();
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }
        Application.Run(new Form1(user));
    }
```

And I'm trying to get a string from my loginForm and then send it to Form1.
But the string is returning nothing..

And here is "login.returnUser();"

```
public string returnUser()
    {
        String user = usernameText.Text;
        return user;
    }
```

This should work correct?

Comment: Have you tried to move `user = login.returnUser();` after `if(login....` ?

Comment: .Net public member names should be UpperCamelCase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're calling `returnUser()` before showing the dialog.
How do you expect it to have a value?

You only want to do that *after* the user types something.

Answer (score 0):

Get the user after `ShowDialog`:

```
using (var login = new loginForm())
{
    // user = login.returnUser(); <-- Too soon
    if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
    user = login.returnUser();
}
```

`ShowDialog` is what causes the dialog to be shown. When the user clicks the button to login, the method returns and your `usernameText` textbox should now have a value.

Answer (score 0):

Get user after show dialog().

```
[STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        String user = null;
        using (var login = new loginForm())
        {

            bool invalid = login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK; 
            user = login.returnUser();
            if(invalid)
               return;
        }
        Application.Run(new Form1(user));
    }
```